# urllib: get utf-8 encoded site source code

Tags: python, encoding, urllib2, utf8-decode

I'm trying to fetch a segment of some website. The script works, however it's a website that has accents such as á, é, í, ó, ú.

When I fetch the site using urllib or urllib2, the site source code is not encoded in utf-8, which I would like it to be, as utf-8 supports these accents.

I believe that the target site is encoded in utf-8 as it contains the following meta tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

My python script:

```
opener = urllib2.build_opener()
opener.addheaders = [('Accept-Charset', 'utf-8')]
url_response = opener.open(url)
deal_html = url_response.read().decode('utf-8')
```

However, I keep getting results that look like they are not encoded un utf-8.

E.g: "Milán" on website = "Mil\xe1n" after urllib2 fetches it

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your script is working correctly.  The `"\xe1"` string is the representation of the `unicode` object resulting from decoding.  For example:

```
>>> "Mil\xc3\xa1n".decode('utf-8')
u'Mil\xe1n'
```

The `"\xc3\xa1"` sequence is the [UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Utf-8) sequence for leter a with diacritic mark: á.

Comment: Ok, I see now that when I print "Mil\xc3\xa1n", it returns Milán, which is perfect. However, when I fetch strings from the source code, and append them to a list, I get "Mil\xc3\xa1n". How can I make this readable (i.e. Milán) in the list or dictionary?

Comment: The list calls `repr()` on each of the items in it, which is why the extended characters get escaped. If you need a more readable representation for debugging purposes, just do something like `[str(x) for x in mylist]`.